# CakePHP Plugin implementation not routing

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin for CakePHP (CakePHP 2.2.3) called LinkElement which takes makes it possible to get a url and hand back a rendered element. My example uses an Ajax tabs table (if there are better ways to do this please say).  I cannot get it to load from a URL.

Example:

localhost/LinkElement/Links/

throws:

```
Error: LinkElementController could not be found.

Error: Create the class LinkElementController below in file: app\Controller\LinkElementController.php

<?php
class LinkElementController extends AppController { }
```

My layout is as follows:

```
/app
    /Plugin
        /LinkElement
            /Controller
                LinkElementAppController.php
                LinksController.php
            /Model
                LinkElementAppModel.php
            /View
                Links/
                    index.ctp
```

LinkElementAppController.php

```
<?php class LinkElementAppController extends AppController { }
```

LinksController.php

```
<?php App::uses('LinkElementAppController', 'LinkElement.Controller');

class LinksController extends LinkElementAppController {}
```

LinkElementAppModel.php

```
<?php class LinkElementAppModel extends AppModel {}
```

Links/index.ctp (just a dummy until I can get the URL working)

```
<h2>Working</h2>
```

Also routes.php

```
CakePlugin::routes();
CakePlugin::load(array('LinkElement'));
```

I realise that this is probably simple, but I cannot see it right now and looking at other answers is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ever be using caps in URLs. :)

The Cake way to access controllers in plugins is to use underscore notation:

`/plugin_name/controller_name/action`

So in your case:

`localhost/link_element/links/<action>`

ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-tips